# How to restrict git from tracking / updating local changes?

Tags: javascript, git, github, gitignore

So, I learn git functions, but cannot make the file `README.md` executed from git branch update in the file `.gitignore`.

I had wrote the next in `.gitignore` but it does not help during push on server.

```
// .gitignore
# readme
README.md
LICENSE
```

Comment: You want to exclude Readme from GIT?

Comment: Yes, just from update, not delete @Melchia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is some crucial information you are missing. `git` tracks files as soon as you add them to the staging area. And once they are committed they will be tracked even **when added** to `.gitignore` and since your `README` is already added to git so `git` will track changes made to this file.

**So** adding it to your `.gitignore` as you already did will not work since it will be tracked by git from now on.

#### How to tell git to ignore local changes?

You can use the `assume-unchanged`

#### `assume-unchanged`

```
// Mark local fule so git will not detect local changes
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

// To get a list of dir's/files that are marked as assume-unchanged
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'

// To un-mark files
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

#### Adding `assume-unchanged` aliases

```
git config --global alias.hide "update-index --assume-unchanged"
git config --global alias.show "update-index --no-assume-unchanged"
git config --global alias.list-unchanged "ls-files -v|grep '^h'"
```

Now your `.gitconfig` should have the following aliases:

```
[alias]
    hide = update-index --assume-unchanged
    unhide = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
    list-unchanged = ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

#### Usage:

```
git hide myfile.ext
git unhide myfile.ext
```

---

If you are using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) you add custom action:
[image]

---

[image]
[image]